Can't get ElevenLabs API in Google AppScript To Return Valid Response
I'm using a Google AppScript to integrate Eleven Labs' API into a Sheet.
Trying to get past this step so that I can do something with a returned file but I can't get past this response code 422. I'm following their javascript example. I started it to lok
https://elevenlabs.io/docs/api-reference/text-to-speech
apiUrlEndPoint = "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/Xb7hH8MSUJpSbSDYk0k2"


const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'xi-api-key': xiApiKey
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: '{"text":"This is the text to convert","model_id":"eleven_multilingual_v2","voice_settings":{"stability":1,"similarity_boost":1}}',
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};

const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrlEndPoint, options);

I've tried variations with stringify and without. Same result.
Response Code: 422
Response Body: {"detail":[{"loc":["body","text"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
Request failed with status code 422
 

update: 8/12/2024 (sorry haven't used StackOverlflow in like 10 years. Just gonna post the snippet that I got to work)
var apiUrlEndPoint = "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/"+voiceId;
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'xi-api-key':apiKey,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "text": inputText,
      "model_id": modelId,
      "voice_settings": {
        "stability": stability,
        "similarity_boost": similarity,
        "use_speaker_boost": speakerBoost,
        "style": style
      }
    }),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrlEndPoint, options);


I ended up resolving this a few weeks ago. Can't remember how to be honest.. I'm not sure how to respond to anyone's edits. Is this a recent functionality of stackoverflow? People just go in and edit your code? To the guy who advised me not share API Keys if you read the key I put as a placeholder the ket was "myAPIKeyWhichIDoHavexiApiKey"

what happened to previous edits other people made? this website is not very intuitive

To "respond" to an edit use @ followed by the editor "normalized" user name (no spaces).

Regarding the "previous edits" click the link "edited number time unit ago". In this case it points to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78781369/revisions. You can find more detailed answers to your questions about using Stack Overflow on [meta].
